# How to set Sql DateTime to null from LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql, datetime, null

I have two cases when I would need to set DateTime field in Sql to null. I use C# and LINQ to SQL Classes. I read many questions on stackoverflow which are like my question but still I feed mine a bit different.

When we insert a new customer.

Corresponding code:

```
 Customer customer = new Customer();
 customer.CustomerName = txt_name.Text;
 customer.DOB = dtp_dob.Checked ? DateTime.Parse(dtp_dob.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")) : //send null here;
```

customer.DOB is System.DateTime.

What I tried is:

**1)**

```
 customer.DOB = dtp_dob.Checked ? DateTime.Parse(dtp_dob.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")) : SqlDateTime.Null;
```

But this will not succeed as SqlDateTime cannot be converted to System.DateTime.

**2)**

```
    DateTime? nullDateTime = new DateTime();
 customer.DOB = dtp_dob.Checked ? DateTime.Parse(dtp_dob.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")) : nullDateTime.Value
```

In this case, build succeeds but it will throw an SqlDateTime overflow exception.

So then how to pass null value

Property of DOB Member in LINQ Dataclass

[image]

Many of them suggest to set Auto Generated Value to true and not to insert any value. True, it works in insert cases.

But now assume, there is already a customer entry where some datetime value is set to DOB field. Now user wants to clear this value (remove the birthdate), then in this case I have to pass a null value using UpdateOn to clear the datetime filed in corresponding customer row.

Thank you very much in advance :)

Comment: It's nullable, couldn't you just set it to `null`?

Comment: `Customer.DOB` should be `DateTime?` rather than `DateTime` if the column is nullable.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You should be able to use:

```
Customer customer = new Customer();
customer.CustomerName = txt_name.Text;
customer.DOB = dtp_dob.Checked 
                  ? DateTime.Parse(dtp_dob.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")) 
                  : (DateTime?) null;
```

Note the cast of `null` to `DateTime?`. The current problem is that the compiler can't work out the type of the conditional expression based on the operands.

The problem with your second attempt is that you're creating a new non-nullable DateTime value, i.e. 1st January 0001 AD. You could change that to:

```
DateTime? nullDateTime = null;
customer.DOB = dtp_dob.Checked 
                  ? DateTime.Parse(dtp_dob.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")) 
                  : nullDateTime;
```

Answer (score 0):

plz try

```
if(dtp_dob.Checked )
{
   customer.DOB = DateTime.Parse(dtp_dob.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"));
}
else
{
   cstomer.DOB =null;
}
```

since DOB is nullable this code will give you what you want. BTW i can't find anything like nullDateTime.Value